# How to use Rails'Active Record in a separated script.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have to run this script: `/scripts/saveData.rb`

And in it, I need to use `ActiveRecord` of my Rails application.
I tried to invoke `Class`, but I get error `"uninitialized constant (NameError)"`.

How can I get a reference to the Rails classes from my `saveData.rb` script?

Rails 3.1

**UPDATED:** how i can invoke a method of a Model? My model is: "Program" (also Active Record). I tried with "Program.method" but it doesnt works, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Which version of rails you are using?

You can run your code in Rails runner like this if you are using Rails 3:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner

```
$ rails runner script/saveData.rb
```

If you are using Rails 2, try this one:

```
$ script/runner script/saveData.rb
```

Comment: Ok, and how i can invoke a method of a Model?
My model is: "Program" (also Active Record).
I tried with "Program.method" but it doesnt works, why?

Comment: is there has any error messages? basically, if your script running through rails's runner, all your methods of your models can be accessible.

Comment: I have always used rake for this, but runner looks pretty handy.

Answer (score 1):

Use [rails runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner).

Barring that, you could create a rake task, or just load the file from the rails console.

Comment: i dont understand. i need to run "Active Record" INSIDE a .rb file

Comment: @user1028100 First of all, you don't "run" ActiveRecord--it's a class. You *use* ActiveRecord. `runner` is one way to access your Rails environment from a script--did you read the link? IMO a rake task would be nicer, but the options provided are the usual choices.

Comment: how i can invoke a method of a Model? My model is: "Program" (also Active Record). I tried with "Program.method" but it doesnt works, why?

Comment: @user1028100 Depends; if it's an instance method you need to call it on an instance. If it's a class method, what you show should work. This is a new question, though, and not related to your first.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to `require` the Rails environment with this at the top of your script:

```
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'environment'))
```

However, you should really consider using a rake task instead.